# Arithmetic in web scraping in a shell

Tags: html, bash, curl, calc, expr

so, I have the example code here:

```
#!/bin/bash
clear

curl -s  https://www.cnbcindonesia.com/market-data/currencies/IDR=/USD-IDR |
html2text |
sed -n '/USD\/IDR/,$p' |
sed -n '/Last updated/q;p' |
tail -n-1 |
head -c+6 && printf "\n"

exit 0
```

this should print out some number range 14000~15000

lets start from the very basic one, what I have to do in order to print `result + 1` ? so if the printout is 14000 and increment it to 1 become 14001. I suppose the result of the html2text is not calculatable since it should be something like string output not integer.

the more advance thing i want to know is how to calculate the result of 2 curl results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I would do, [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) + [xidel](/questions/tagged/xidel):

```
$ num=$(xidel -se '//div[@class="mark_val"]/span[1]/text()' 'https://url')
$ num=$((${num//,/}+1)) # num was 14050
$ echo $num
```

### Output

```
14051
```

### Explanations

```
$((...))
```

is an arithmetic substitution. After doing the arithmetic, the whole thing is replaced by the value of the expression. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ArithmeticExpression

Command Substitution: `"$(cmd "foo bar")"` causes the command 'cmd' to be executed with the argument 'foo bar' and "$(..)" will be replaced by the *output*. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/002 and http://mywiki.wooledge.org/CommandSubstitution

### Bonus

You can compute directly in [xidel](/questions/tagged/xidel), thanks [Reino](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2703456/reino) using [xquery](/questions/tagged/xquery) syntax :

```
$ xidel -s <url> e 'replace(//div[@class="mark_val"]/span[1],",","") + 1'
```

And to do addition arithmetic of 2 values :

```
$ xidel -s <url> -e '
    let $num:=replace(//div[@class="mark_val"]/span[1],",","")
    return $num + $num
'
```

Comment: Hi Gilles, thank you for introducing me to xidel, it's much easier now to do simple web scraping with xpath capability tool. however, when i trying out these command, I got an error in terminal. it says `test.sh: 7: test.sh: Bad substitution` , i saved the script as test.sh btw.

Comment: Can you run this with `bash script.sh` ? It's required. Or replace `${num//,/}` bash parameter expansion by `tr` or `sed`

Comment: ah! i was using `sh test.sh` , i thought it wont cause any problem. cool now it works.

Comment: so If i about to combine 2 links, it would be like this?


`$ num=$(xidel -se '//div[@class="mark_val"]/span[1]/text()' 'https://url')

$ num=$((${num//,/}+1)) # num was 14050

$ nam=$(xidel -se '//div[@class="mark_val"]/span[1]/text()' 'https://url')

$ nam=$((${nam//,/}+1)) # nam was 14050

$ echo $num + $nam`

?

Comment: `echo $((num+nam))`

Comment: oh right, cool now all my problem solved, thank you very much

Comment: @GillesQuenot `xidel -s <url> -e 'replace(//div[@class="mark_val"]/span[1],",","") + 1'`

Comment: @Reino: Are you a dev from `xidel` ? :)

Comment: @AhiungLim If all you want is 14050+14050, then there's no need for multiple `xidel` calls: `xidel -s <url> -e 'let $num:=replace(//div[@class="mark_val"]/span[1],",","") return $num + $num'`

Comment: @GillesQuenot No, I'm not. Just an active user.

Comment: Added this as 'Bonus'